# Generate number of columns dynamically according to screen size in android grid layout

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am using grid layout which has a textview to implement drag and drop in android. I  have a problem in generating number of columns as I am CHANGING THE TEXTVIEW SIZE ACCORDING TO THE TEXT AREA. For eg. if the textview contains word "TEST" then the width of the textview will be according to that.

I used the below code to generate number of columns according to screen size

```
    float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
    number = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    columns = (int) ((float) number / (float) scalefactor);
```

When I use this code, it generates same number of columns regardless of the WIDTH OF THE TEXTVIEW. For eg. I am getting output like,

[image: OUTPUT]

My expected output is ,

[image: expectedoutput]

I want the textview to adjust automatically in first row since the space is available in first row. In short, I want the column count increment to stop once the width of the phone is reached. I even tried the below code,

```
    int static totaltextarea ;
    totaltextarea = totaltextarea + widths; //widths is the text area of the textview
    if(totaltextarea <=number) //number is the screen width
     {
     columncount++
     }
```

It didn't help me. The columns are going out of the screen when I implement this methods. Please help.

P.S : I want the textview width to be the width of the text area .